# How to hide legend with Plotly Express and Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to learn Plotly by firstly creating a simple bar chart in Plotly Express and then updating it with Plotly to finesse it. I would like to hide the legend.

I am trying to update the original figure by hiding the legend, and I can't get it to work. [This is my traceback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb2DX.jpg).

And my code

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly_express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Documents/Python/CKANMay.csv')

fig = px.bar(df, x="Publisher", y="Views", color="Publisher", barmode="overlay")

fig.update(fig, showlegend="false")
```

[This is what the chart looks like now with the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI3cr.jpg). Basically, I want that awful legend on the right to go away

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
my_data = [go.Bar( x = df.Publisher, y = df.Views)]
my_layout = go.Layout({"title": "Views by publisher",
                       "yaxis": {"title":"Views"},
                       "xaxis": {"title":"Publisher"},
                       "showlegend": False})

fig = go.Figure(data = my_data, layout = my_layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

- the argument `showlegend` is part of layout object which you did not specify in your code
- The code may also work if you do not wrap the layout object `my_layout` inside a `go.Layout()`. It could work by simply keeping `my_layout` a dictionary
- as for `plotly.express`, try `fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)`. All the arguments are the same. Accessing them varies slightly.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the question entirely - how does one hide the legend in Plotly Express?

Answer (score 62):

After creating the figure in plotly, to disable the legend you can make use of this command:

```
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

For Advanced users:
You can also enable/disable the legend for individual traces in a figure by setting the showlegend property of each trace. For instance:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2],
    y=[1, 2],
    showlegend=False))
```

You can view the examples here: https://plotly.com/python/legend/

Answer (score 11):

The issue with your original code is that `fig.update()` doesn't take `fig` as an argument. That line could just be `fig.update(layout_showlegend=False)`

Comment: can also customize via `fig.update_layout(legend={"xanchor":"center", "yanchor":"top"})` Docs: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-legend