# Hide legend in plotly express (not Plotly)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-express

I have a scatteplot I’m trying to present, with lots of symbols and colors. This makes the default legend unreadable.
Is there a way to hide the legend (equivalent, or similar to showlegend=False when using traces and graph objects)?

Here’s my graphing line:

`fig = px.scatter(df_revised, x='df_x', y = 'df_y', color = 'type', symbol = 'country', hover_data = ['id'], marginal_y="histogram", marginal_x="histogram")`

I've seen the question [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712486/how-to-hide-legend-with-plotly-express-and-plotly), but that is not useful, as it's changing the plotting library to plotly rather that the express version.

I have also tried `fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)` but that return an error `AttributeError: 'ExpressFigure' object has no attribute 'update_layout'`

Comment: If you’re seeing that error you’re using an older version of Plotly/Plotly Express... upgrading to the latest version will enable this pattern :)

Comment: Also please note: Plotly Express is now part of Plotly and has always used it internally, so there’s no real distinction between the two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the version you have right now, `fig.layout.showlegend = False` should work (and continues to work with the latest version!).