# How to remove labels generated by the "color" attribute in a plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly.graph_objects to plot a Time Series, but the labels that generated the "color"  attribute use all the space. I want to know how if there is an attribute in update_layout() for disable those labels

[image]

code:

```
fig = px.line(
    df_complete,
    x="Month",
    y="Count",
    color="Code Description",
    text="Count",  
    hover_data=[
        "Month",
        "Code Description",
        "Count",
    ], 
    line_shape="linear",  
)


fig.update_layout(
    title="Count of activities per month",
    xaxis=dict(title="Month"),
    yaxis=dict(title="Count"),
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you share the specific code that you used to generate this plot?

Comment: done bro. I only can share that part of code :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide legend with Plotly Express and Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712486/how-to-hide-legend-with-plotly-express-and-plotly)

Answer (score 0):

```
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

[image]
reference:
https://plotly.com/python/legend/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the legend with `showlegend` option as indicated in the reference (https://plotly.com/python/legend/#showing-and-hiding-the-legend).

Your code updated:

```
fig = px.line(
    df_complete,
    x="Month",
    y="Count",
    color="Code Description",
    text="Count",  
    hover_data=[
        "Month",
        "Code Description",
        "Count",
    ], 
    line_shape="linear",  
)


fig.update_layout(
    title="Count of activities per month",
    xaxis=dict(title="Month"),
    yaxis=dict(title="Count"),
    showlegend=False # Remove the legend
)

fig.show()
```